Grover with randomized oracle
I'm sorry if this is a stupid question. I want to know about the behavior of Grover's algorithm with oracle having a low one-sided probability of error. So if $f(x)=0$ my oracle returns $0$ and if $f(x)=1$ my oracle returns $1$ with probability $1-p$. Is it true that if $p=o(\frac{1}{\sqrt(n)})$, where $n$ is the size of the codomain of $f$ then Grover's algorithm still returns $x$ with constant probability?

Is $n$ the number of qubits (bits) used for the codomain of $f$? You can always amplify by repeating Grover and try until success.

Are you more interested in how a standard implementation of Grover works in this scenario, or whether the algorithm can be modified to work over a much greater range of $p$?

n is the size of the codomain of f.

The range of p is not a concern for me. I want to understand how to do a search with a nonperfect oracle.
